# Problemas com o sistema de login

Tags: php

Estou com problemas no sistema de login, o fato é numa das paginas do sistema em especial na pagina `perfil.php`.

Para explicar melhor vou mostra todo o processo do sistema de login.

Página `cadastro.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"/>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>cadastrar</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">P&aacute;gina Inicial</a>

        </li>



    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabela">

    <form action=" cadastro_db.php" method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr >
    <td class="tabelinha" colspan="2">Cadastrar

    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Nome</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
      <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Email</td>
    <td  width="150" class="tabelinha" id="senha"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Idade</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
      <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Cidade</td>
    <td  width="150" class="tabelinha" id="senha"><input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Login</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
      <input type="text" name="login" id="login" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Senha</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
      <input type="text" name="senha" id="senha" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">Imagem</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
      <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" />
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cad"/>
    </label></td>


  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label>
      <div align="center">
       <br /> <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="cadastrar" /><br />
      </div>
    </label></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </form>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Página `cadastro_db.php`:

```
<?php 


include("connection.php");

$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$idade=$_POST['idade'];
$cidade=$_POST['cidade'];
$login=$_POST['login'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];

if(!is_file($_FILES['foto'] ['tmp_name'])){
    echo"
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Selecione uma imagem')</script>
    ";

}

else {
    $foto=$_FILES['foto'] ['name'];
    $foto= str_replace("","",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("à","a",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("á","a",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("á","a",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("é","e",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("è","e",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("ì","i",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("í","i",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("ó","o",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("õ","o",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("õ","o",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("ç","c",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("ù","u",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("û","u",$foto);
    $foto= str_replace("ü","u",$foto);

    $foto=strtolower($foto);

    $tipos = array("image/pjeg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/pjeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"  );
    $arqType = $_FILES['foto'] ['type'];
    if(array_search($arqType, $tipos)== false){
        echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=index.php'>
             <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Formato Inválido')</script>";
    }
           else{
        if(file_exists("fotos/$foto")){
            $a = 1;
            while (file_exists("fotos/($a)$foto")){
                $a++;
            }
            $foto= "[".$a."]$foto";

        }

            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto'] ['tmp_name'],"fotos/".$foto)){
             echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=index.php'>

             <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('falha!')</script>";

            }

           $sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO usuario(nome, email, idade, cidade, login, senha, foto) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$idade', '$cidade', '$login', '$senha', '$foto')");
   // Fecha a conexão antes de redirecionar
  header("Location: index.php");

             }
              mysqli_close($db);










}


?>
```

Página `connection.php`:

```
<?php 

  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "angola");
  mysqli_select_db($db, "login_senha");

?>
```

Página `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"/>
<title>Entrar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Página Inicial</a>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="cadastro.php">Cadastrar</a>

        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabela">

    <form action="logar.php" method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr >
    <td class="tabelinha" colspan="2">ENTRAR

    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">login</td>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="150"><label>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" />

    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabelinha"  width="80">senha</td>
    <td  width="150" class="tabelinha" id="senha"><input type="text" name="senha" id="senha" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label>
      <div align="center">
       <br /> <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Entrar" /><br />
      </div>
    </label></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Página `logar.php`:

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
$con= mysql_select_db("login_senha");

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha_post = $_POST['senha'];


$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($cont==0){ 
        echo"
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Login não existe')</script>
        ";
    } else { 
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            if($linha['senha']!=$senha_post){
                echo "
                <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
                <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Senha não corresponde')</script>
                "; 
            } else {
               $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
               $_SESSION['login_senha']=$senha;
                header("Location: perfil.php");
            }
        }
}

mysql_close($db);
```

Página `perfil.php`:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
$con= mysql_select_db("login_senha");

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $enviar = $_POST['enviar'];

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");


while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $senha =$linha['senha'];
 }
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);


 if($cont==0){
     echo"
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Login não existe')</script>
    ";
 }else{
     if(  $senha_db!=$senha){
     echo"
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Senha não corresponde')</script>
    "; 
 }else{
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
     $_SESSION['login_senha']=$senha;
     header("Location: ficha.php");

 }
 }
 mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Página

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("login_senha");

    $login = $_POST['login']; nesta linha ele parece com erro:

/*este erro: Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 6 */

    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='($login)'");
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">Voltar</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Administração</a>

        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <?
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    ?>
    <div class="perfil">
      <img src="fotos/<?php echo $linha['foto']; ?>" alt="imagem de perfil" title="imagem de perfil"  />
    </div>
    <div class="dados">
        <p>Nome</p><p><?php echo $linha['nome']; ?></p>    
        <p>Email</p><p><?php echo $linha['email'];?></p>
        <p>idade</p><p>40<?php echo $linha['idade'];?></p>    
        <p>Cidade</p><p><?php echo $linha['cidade'];?></p>
    </div>
    <? } else {  ?>
     <div class="perfil">
        Este usuário não está logado ou não foi encontrado.
     </div>
    <? } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: login='($login)' -> troque para login='{$login}'

Comment: Troque também: $login = $_POST['login'];  para : if(isset($_POST['login'])){ $login = $_POST['login']; } else { echo "Login Vazio."; }

Answer (score 0):

O seu html ficou horroroso, mas, de acordo com o erro que o PHP está a dizer, alguma coisa no processo de `POST` não está a acontecer de acordo com aquilo que estás a espera.

Podes saber se `$_POST['login']` existe com [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) ou [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Depois de saber se ela existe, `if (!empty($_POST['login']) { $login = $_POST['login']; } else { die('you have no login field'); }`